# Google Glass XE21 Bluetooth LE Disconnects automatically

Tags: bluetooth, aero-glass

I am trying to write an application for google glass to read the RSSI value of a stickNFind Beacon on regular intervals (800 milli seconds) for which I need to connect to gatt server. 
When I try to connect to the gatt server in BluetothLE mode, it disconnects immediately.

When I am connecting to gatt server using this: 
    **mConnectedGatt = btDevice.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);**

I get this in the call back: 
    **onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=4 device=E1:FC:AF:DB:E3:FC**

and then immidietly I get this in the call back: 
    **onClientConnectionState() - status=62 clientIf=4 device=E1:FC:AF:DB:E3:FC**

The same code is working fine on my nexus 7. 
Does anyone has any idea if Google Glass's support is good enough to connect to gatt server?

I don't understand the status 62 code...please help